# C# TFS Creation with rest API - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use rest api to create work items on tfs 2015 with batch mode while the error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

The work items are like followings: 1 new PBI with two child tasks while created PBI is going to be child of given UR id.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var batchRequest = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchRequests), Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json");
var method = new HttpMethod("POST");

// send the request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, _settings.TfsUri + "/" + CreateWorkItemsBatch) { Content = batchRequest };
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

While in the response, value.code = 400, message is "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchRequests) is like followings:

```
[{"method":"PATCH","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"},
"body":[
{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.IterationPath","value":"eCommerce\\EOL-QA"},
{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"QA Activities: Selenium tests - Self-report - 446259: Dashboard (Multi-customer user): Widget - Recent samples"},
{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":{"rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url":"http://alm.eurofins.local/tfs/EurofinsCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1529787"}},
{"op":"add","path":"/id","value":"-1"}],
"uri":"/eCommerce/_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=2.2"},

{"method":"PATCH","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"},
"body":[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Main task"},
{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.IterationPath","value":"eCommerce\\EOL-QA"},
{"op":"add","path":"/id","value":"-2"},
{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":{"rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url":"http://alm.eurofins.local/tfs/eurofinscollection/_apis/wit/workitems/-1"}}],
"uri":"/eCommerce/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=2.2"},


{"method":"PATCH","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"},
"body":[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Review Task"},
{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.IterationPath","value":"eCommerce\\EOL-QA"},
{"op":"add","path":"/id","value":"-3"},
{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":{"rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url":"http://alm.eurofins.local/tfs/eurofinscollection/_apis/wit/workitems/-1"}}],
"uri":"/eCommerce/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=2.2"}]
```

Comment: Can you share the full rest URL?

Comment: request.ToString() "Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://alm.eurofins.local/tfs/eurofinscollection/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n}" string

Comment: I get the problem resolved that the IterationPath is deleted by someone..After I change that, the issue is fixed.